# How do you say "build it up too much" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

Often, and usually when I'm describing to someone a movie or a book I really like, I'll say something like, well, I'll leave it at that because I don't want to *build it up too much*.  By this I don't mean "exaggerate."  When I use this phrase I am trying to say that I don't want to create such lofty expectations in the mind of the person that they couldn't possibly enjoy it because the expectations for the thing I am recommending are now so high that the actual experience of it has the potential to fall short of my glowing description (because value, like beauty, is always in the eye of the beholder).

What makes this phrase — build it up too much — difficult to translate is the fact that a standard definition of this phrase doesn't appear to be found in English (at least I wasn't able to find one easily).  Nevertheless, it is a fairly common phrase in colloquial English, and I have a feeling the following translations are a bit too literal:

> From [**Reverso**](https://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/I+don%27t+want+to+build+it+up+too+much.):
> No quiero construir demasiado.
>
> From [**DeepL**](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator#en/es/I%20don%27t%20want%20to%20build%20it%20up%20too%20much.) and [**Google Translate**](https://translate.google.com/?rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS861US861&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=es&text=I%20don%27t%20want%20to%20build%20it%20too%20much.):
> No quiero
> construirlo demasiado.
>
> **DeepL** also adds as alternatives:
> No quiero aumentarlo mucho.
> No quiero construirlo mucho.

How would you, especially you native speakers of Spanish, translate this phrase?

---

A menudo, y normalmente cuando le describo a alguien una película o un libro que me gusta mucho, digo algo como, well, I'll leave it at that because I don't want to *build it up too much*.  Con esto no quiero decir "exagerar".  Cuando utilizo esta frase intento decir que no quiero crear expectativas tan elevadas en la mente de la persona que no puedan disfrutarlo porque las expectativas de lo que estoy recomendando son ahora tan altas que la experiencia real de ello tiene el potencial de quedarse corta en mi brillante descripción (porque el valor, como la belleza, está siempre en el ojo del espectador).

Lo que dificulta la traducción de esta frase — build it up too much — es el hecho de que no parece que se encuentre una definición estándar de esta frase en inglés (por lo menos yo no fui capaz de encontrar una fácilmente).  Sin embargo, es una frase bastante común en el inglés coloquial, y tengo la sensación de que las siguientes traducciones son un poco demasiado literales:

[Véanse arriba.]

¿Cómo traduciríais/traducirían esta frase, especialmente vosotros/ustedes, los hispanohablantes nativos?

*Traducción realizada (en parte) con la versión gratuita del traductor [www.DeepL.com/Translator.](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator.)*

Comment: Esas traducciones de Reverso y Google son espantosas y no tienen el menor sentido, eso seguro. "No quiero crear demasiada expectativa", quizá?

Comment: I think that the definition 1.2 found in the Oxford Dictionary matches your description https://www.lexico.com/definition/build_up : 1.2 build someone or something up, build up someone or something -> Promote or support someone or something.

Comment: @Gaviota creo que eso podría muy bien convertirse en una respuesta...

Comment: @wimi Te parece? No respondí porque Lisa de hecho en la explicación usa prácticamente la misma expresión (que no quiere crear expectativas tan elevadas...).

Comment: @Gaviota es verdad, pero en cualquier caso me parece la expresión más natural, por lo que tiene sentido tenerlo como respuesta. Tu decisión en cualquier caso :)

Comment: @wimi ok! Ya lo respondo así Charlie no me pega :P

Comment: @Gaviota pero yo qué voy a pegar, con lo pacífico que soy... ^__^U

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voy a proponer una variación de la [respuesta de Gaviota](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/37032/12637) que también usa la voz *[expectativa](https://dle.rae.es/expectativa)*:

> 1. f. Esperanza de realizar o conseguir algo.
> 2. f. Posibilidad razonable de que algo suceda.

Sin embargo, yo voy a combinar esta palabra con este verbo:

> **[condicionar](https://dle.rae.es/condicionar)**
>
> 2. tr. Influir de manera importante en el comportamiento de alguien o en el desarrollo de algo. *La enfermedad la condicionó en su vida posterior. El estado de la vía condiciona la velocidad del tren.*

Así, el ejemplo que propones yo lo diría en español de la siguiente manera:

> Voy a parar aquí porque no quiero condicionar tus expectativas.

Un ejemplo de uso de la expresión, sacado del CREA:

> *Cualquier satisfacción concreta de sus deseos [...] más bien que hacer olvidar las insatisfacciones anteriores, las traían en masa a la memoria, como un dato a la vez abstracto e individualizado, como un resumen siempre vivo, que condicionaba todas sus expectativas, enrareciéndolas.*
>
> Álvaro Pombo, "El metro de platino iridiado", 1990 (España).

---

Por cierto, la expresión se puede encontrar en el diccionario de Cambridge:

> **[build sth/sb up](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/build-sth-sb-up)**
>
> to praise something or someone in a way that will influence people's opinions; to make a person feel more confident

Comment: Bueno bueno, te descuidás un segundo acá y te agarran a sopapos!

Comment: Una vez más, estoy impresionada con tu investigación, Charlie, pero también debo admitir que me siento un poco avergonzada por no extender mi propia investigación lo suficiente para consultar un diccionario bastante importante como el de Cambridge, especialmente porque me encantan los libros que Cambridge publica sobre el uso del inglés.  ¡Me rendí demasiado pronto!  Sin embargo, todavía me habría esforzado con una buena traducción al español, así que, gracias.  Y gracias también por el extracto de Álvaro Pombo ... ¡Qué buen hallazgo y buen toque!  ¡¡Bien hecho!!

Answer (score 6):

Agrego lo que había sugerido en un comentario, si bien es similar a lo que ya usas en la pregunta.
En el escenario que describes, yo diría:

> No te quiero crear/generar demasiada expectativa.

O bien:

> No te quiero crear/generar falsas expectativas.